# How to clear pool filter pressure gauge that is stuck?

Tags: water-pressure, pool, filter

I've got an in-ground pool, and a DE filter from Jandy. The pressure gauge is in an assembly bolted to the top. The assembly looks like something like this (image from catalog, mine is pretty much identical):

[image: Jandy gauge]

Today, when I powered the system down, the pressure reading didn't change. I pulled the gauge assembly off and tried blowing it out, removing the relief valve, etc, etc, to no avail. I have to assume something has gotten stuck in the gauge inlet.

Is there any good way to fix this? At the moment I can't even figure out how to get the thing apart.

The ring on the front (where clean/dirty are written) does rotate, and if I have no other answer, I'm going to try prying that off and see where it leads me.

UPDATED: @mikes had the right answer - swap the thing out. I ended up swapping out the whole unit, as I had no idea how to (non-destructively) get it apart. Someone else might like to know how to disassemble the thing in order to get at the actual pressure gauge itself:

- Remove the trim ring. I found a notch on the bottom and pried with a screwdriver
  [image: Ring removed]
- Unscrew the pressure gauge. It's normally threaded, however whatever they used as a sealant didn't want to let go for me. Excessive force may be required. Because I wasn't sure of what I was looking at, and thought perhaps it was formed in place somehow, I ended up cutting the thing in half to find out.
  [image: Cut apart]

Thus, we can see that as long as you can manage to get enough force on it to unscrew the pressure gauge, it should be possible to replace JUST the gauge portion, instead of the entire unit as I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience with pressure gauges is that yours is broken and unrepairable. The odds of an obstruction causing your issue is a long shot at best. You may be able to replace it with off the shelf parts. If you can connect a "T" fitting to the mounting hole install a gauge on one side and maybe an automotive radiator petcock to the other side. This will give a pressure reading and a air bleed port.

Comment: It very likely is a bourdon tube with mechanical linkage; impractical to repair either.